# Module loading react components in Apache environment without Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am currently working on adding a React based section to a website. The data needed to update in real-time without complicating the code with the likes of jQuery. I landed on using React with a pub/sub system to retrieve updates using Node and Socket.io, however, Node is only being used for updating data. The React pages are not be accessed by Node, but rather by Apache. I am including React, ReactDOM, and a standalone version of Babel in the development version.

So, my question is **how can I go about separating out my React components into .js files and requiring them like in Node?**

I looked into RequireJS and Browserify, but they didn't quite seem to get the job done. I need a way that I can edit and include them separate in the dev environment, but they need to be concated and minified on live automagically. Our build process already uses Jenkins, so if a solution was available that could hook into Jenkins, that would be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend bundling your JavaScript code using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), a Node.js based build tool that lets you concatenate and minify your code easily. You create a webpack.config.js file in your projects root and run it on your Jenkins build agent using *node webpack*.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance on the subject, but how would I use components locally in a WAMP dev environment if I have to bundle them with webpack? I have scanned help docs and articles on webpack, browserify, etc. but they never really cover this, at least enough for me to follow along.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. You simply create a JavaScript bundle file with webpack, then add a script tag to your HTML page (or PHP template) to load it, then deploy the JS bundle to your Apache server along with your other static resources.

Comment: For local development, webpack has a watch option that makes it create a new bundle automatically each time you change your JavaScript source files.

Comment: I mean, during development wouldn't I have to rebundle the js files every time I make a change? Is there no in-browser solution that loads all the files individually when I am developing, but can bundle when deployed with Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, like it said, webpack can rebundle automatically. It works pretty well, and quickly. You can even use hot module reloading to automatically update your HTML page in your browser without having to hit the reload button.

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick Hund already recommended, you should use a module bundler. There are several options, but I use - like Patrick Hund - [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).

**What does webpack actually do?**

It loads all the files that you specify - which are mostly files required in your project - and bundles them into one file.

**How is it to be used?**

You need a config file where you specify mainly three things:

- The entry file (the root of your hierarchy)
- The output files (the bundled file)
- The loaders of the files required in your system to work.

You can also specify plugins, to enable for example Hot Module Replacement, to start a dashboard of the bundling process, etc.. But that is not mandatory and to start maybe you don't need this.

**Too much?**

Now you may think that this is too much work for development if you have to constantly rebundle all your files on every change. But it comes with some prebuilt scripts that include a `watch` option which does this for you and more comfortable the Hot Module Replacement which updates your browser on every change without you even have to refresh it.

For production environments you can create another config file in which you leave just what you want (e.g. Hot Module Replacement is not recommended for production) and that's it.

So it all falls down to these config files. You can have a look at [this one](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/universal/webpack.config.js), which was the one I used to understand as it was minified to what I just told you.

To integrate it to your project, you need to match the file of your `index.html` in which you load your js scripts and your output files and for development purposes you may want to use a dev server, which it can be the [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server).